# IBM Bluemix and RedHat/SUSE Linux compatibility / workarounds

Tags: ibm-cloud, rhel, suse, virtual-server

I want Bluemix to host some IBM software. The IBM software only installs on RHEL or SUSE so using Bluemix Virtual Servers is not possible (Centos/Debian support only).

Is there another way I can install this IBM software in Bluemix?
Is there a Virtual Servers workaround to get a RHEL or SUSE operating system to install on?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Could you be more specific about what software products? Many of IBM's products are available as cloud service or as Docker image to run in the Bluemix container service.

Comment: Hi, my remit is to create HowtoGuides for integrating IBM products in Bluemix as though I were a client trying to do this for themselves. My remit as a whole is such that full functionality of the IBM products is needed so any cut-down versions available as Bluemix Apps is not in scope for me. Thanks for your response though. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested you could check if the product you need is provided as a Cloud service. However generally speaking on Virtual Servers (Virtual Machines) on Bluemix you can use a custom image (running RHEL or SUSE). As reported on [Bluemix Virtual Servers docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_index):

> A virtual server image is a file that includes a virtual disk with an
>   operating system installed on it.
>
> You use a virtual server image to create a virtual server. You can use
>   an image that is provided by IBM, a customized virtual server image,
>   or a snapshot that you took of another virtual server.
>
> Important: In Bluemix, you can upload virtual server images that are
>   supported by OpenStack and have qcow2 format only.

For more information, see [Virtual server images - Private virtual server images](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_default_images).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips.

I got hold of a RHEL7.0 image from Red Hat and uploaded it to a Virtual Server in Bluemix. It shows as being RHEL7.0 but is inaccessible either via Public or Private IP addresses. Looks like a compatibaility issue.

I will delete and start again see if I can get it to work.